# while installing HAXM getting some warning message and 'silent_install.bat' is not recognized error..........please help someone

Tags: android, haxm

Running Intel® HAXM installer
'silent_install.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel®  follow the instructions found android/articles/installation-instructions-for-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows
Done

Comment: Please, add more details, what installer you are currently running, what instructions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

silent_install.bat is a part of a zip archive that you have to download for installing HAXM.

This is the link to latest release for Windows: 
https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/download/v7.6.5/haxm-windows_v7_6_5.zip

After download, unpack it, copy the path from explorer header, run cmd as administrator and CD to unpacked location:

```
cd C:\Users\***\Downloads\haxm-windows_v7_6_5
silent_install.bat
```